# How to create JFrame in the same thread so that it blocks?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

For debug purposes, I need to draw image on the screen in a simple window.

Swing handles all it's events in a separate message loop thread. That means that if I do the following:

```
   while(true) {
     //Get screenshot
     BufferedImage screenshot = MSWindow.screenshot();
     //Create JFrame
     JFrame frame = new JFrame();
     Container main = frame.getContentPane();
     //This layout should force the JLabel as large as the window, am I right?
     main.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
     //Create JLabel to display the screenshot
     JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(screenshot));
     main.add(label);
     frame.pack();
     frame.setVisible(true);
     //Delay is allways good when meddling up with dangerous things
     Thread.sleep(2000);
   }
```

... I end up with many many JFrames.

[image: image description]

I used to use JDialog which is blocking and stops thread until you press OK:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, scrollPane, message, javax.swing.JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

This has a flaw though - you can't see the debug window on the taskbar. Sometimes, it's hard to find where the window ended up. This is why I want to switch to JFrame.

My question is straight up this: How to make **current thread wait until JFrame is closed**?

Answer (score 2):

> How to create JFrame in the same thread so that it blocks?

Use a modal JDialog.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, scrollPane, message, javax.swing.JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

> This has a flaw though - you can't see the debug window on the taskbar.

Don't use null for the dialog owner. Make sure you specify the owner JFrame. Whenever you click on the taskbar icon the frame and child dialog will both show up.

Comment: So I'd probably have to keep some static JFrame instance, or create JFrame before the modal dialog?

Comment: @TomášZato, I'm guessing you click a button or something to display your debug window. You could use the `SwingUtilities.windowForCompoenent(...)` to get the frame the button is displayed on.

Comment: I generate the GUI anytime a function is called. I use it to debug computer vision.

Comment: `I generate the GUI anytime a function is called.` again I'm guessing this code is called from somewhere within your JFrame application. Then maybe you can use the `KeyboardFocusManager`. It also has a method to return the active Window.

Answer (score 1):

Build your GUI **outside** the loop **once** and then use

```
 // read new component data
 screenshot = MSWindow.screenshot();
 // modify components
 label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(screenshot));     

 // force the frame to repaint its chilfren
 frame.revalidate();
 frame.pack();
```

to "refresh" it inside the loop.

Comment: The thing is that the code in my question is wrapped in debug function called `showImage`. Otherwise, you're right.

Comment: Split your logic. Have one function that prepares your GUI and another that updates it. Fire the first at the point you start your debugging and limit  `showImage` just to the update part.

Comment: That would not be practical. I'm really using it like a `System.out.println` for images.

Comment: @TomášZato: this actually could work just fine. If you're keeping the GUI visible, you could create your images off the Swing thread, then notify the GUI on the Swing thread which would then display them.